# How can I alternate between method calls?

Tags: java, if-statement, round-robin

I want to call two methods, but I want to call only one of them at a time.

The next time I want to call the one that was'nt called before, kind of a *Round Robin* technique

Example:

```java
void mainMethod() {
    Obj val;

    if (somthing)
        val = implMethod1();
    else {
        val = implMethod2();
    }
}
```

Using a if-statement is something that can be done.
But is there any *out of the box* thing that I can use to achieve the same?

Comment: if-*statement*.

Comment: If it's just two statements use a boolean flag, if you have more methods use an integer along with a switch and some modulo operation.

Comment: Use a [Queue](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html) with two [Function](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Function.html)s (one function for each method which needs to be called). Poll the function from the Queue, call it and then add it back into the Queue. This way the method which needs to be used next will be in the top of the Queue all the time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [AtomicBoolean](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicBoolean.html) for thread safety *Round Robin*:

```java
AtomicBoolean roundRobin = new AtomicBoolean(false);

void mainMethod() {
    Object val;
    if (roundRobin.compareAndSet(false, true)) {
        val = implMethod1();
    } else {
        val = implMethod2();
        roundRobin.set(false);
    }
}
```

> A boolean value that may be updated atomically.

Comment: This is only thread safe if `implMethod*`s are thread safe too

Comment: @Lino you have a point, but it's a black box, as the rest of OP code

Comment: This is not thread safe, this is possible that implMethod2 are called multiple time in a raw.

Answer (score 2):

Just declare a `boolean` variable in your class:

```java
public class MainClass {
    private boolean useMethod1 = true;
    public void mainMethod() {
        if (useMethod1) {
            method1();
        } else {
            method2();
        }
        useMethod1 = !useMethod1;
    }
}
```

You can do the same things in `static`:

- If you don't want to instantiate an object
- If you want it thread safe add `synchronized` before `mainMethod()`

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if I understood the question correctly:

```java
boolean first = true;
if (somthing && first) {
    val = implMethod1();
    first = false;
} else {
    val = implMethod2();
    first = true;
}
```

Comment: This does not help OP, who obviously wants to know what to do in `something`.

Comment: After edit what is the role of `first`? as you dont use it

Comment: Note that `first` should not be at that position, otherwise you could as well write `it(true)` (assuming you meant `if(first)` ).

Comment: 2 upvote and I didn't find this answer as useful. am I missing something to understand?

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood the question, can you be more specific?

Comment: @NiVeR do you mean, that `something` is not defined?

Comment: @Andronicus even if it is, it is not clear how it is used/updated

Comment: From the question I cannot infer, what it is

Answer (score 1):

```java
static int count = 0;

void mainMethod() {
    Obj val;

    if (somthing && count % 2 == 0)
        val = implMethod1();
    else {
        val = implMethod2();
    }
    count++;
}
```

You can try above code.

Comment: you do realize that count is local variable?

Comment: count is a local variable so it will reset to `0` everytime you can this method so this wont work

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `somthing` is a `boolean` variable, you can achieve it by using this strategy:

```java
void mainMethod() {
    Obj val;

    if (somthing) {
        val = implMethod1();
        somthing = false;
    } else {
        val = implMethod2();
        somthing = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```java
private static boolean check = true;

void mainMethod() {
    Obj val;

    if (check) {
        val = implMethod1();
        check = !check;
    } else {
        val = implMethod2();
        check = !check;
    }
}
```

This may help you.

Comment: It is not thread safe . You would have to synchronize its access.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a queue:

Inizialize queue:

```
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Queue;

....

Queue<String> methodQueue = new LinkedList<>();
methodQueue.add("implMethod1");
```

Use queue in your method:

```
void mainMethod(methodQueue){
 somthing = methodQueue.poll()
 Obj val;

 if(somthing.equals('implMethod1'))
    val = implMethod1();
    methodQueue.add('implMethod2')

 else{
    val = implMethod2();
    methodQueue.add('implMethod1')
 }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake. When you switch from language to another it is possibile to make a mistake. In javascript and python you can make a string check equals value with "==".

Comment: Since you are at it why not using RB-tree? :)